# Cannot get mainBundle resources (returns null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to access a resource file I added in the app using relative pathing. I've read that I was supposed to use something like this :

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *filePath = [[mainBundle resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];
fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:resourcePath];
```

Except this isn't working. With NSLog, I am able to confirm `mainBundle` isn't `null` and `resourcePath` returns something like this:
`/Users/tom/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX/MyApp_Demo.app/myFile.txt`

I've tried many things, such as adding the name of directory where the resource is located, that would be `Ressources/myFile`, but nothing is yielding any result.

I'm a total beginner with Objective-C but I have to tinker with legacy code and I have to deal with this, so any help is much appreciated.

Side note:
this is what the project structure looks like from Xcode:

[image: project structure in Xcode]

Meanwhile, in Finder, the Ressources directory isn't inside the MyApp directory, rather they're on the same level inside the project directory. I wonder if that could be the problem.

Side note 2:

`NSString *filePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];`

returns `(null)` after logging in the console.

Comment: "@"resourceName"" Shouldn't this be `myFile` instead?, or is it because you replaced it in your screenshot? In noticed there is only one "s", and "two" in the folder name. So is the correct name?

Comment: @Larme Yes, the names matched correctly in the project, I changed them here to hide the real name just in case. The name of the resource is good, and I'm not sure if `Ressources` should be called `Resource` for Objective-C to find it.

Comment: Is the file added to your app target?

Comment: @Larme ok so I have the file in the resource Tags of the project, if I do `NSString *filePath = [[mainBundle resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];` it seems to find a path but I can't use that path to create the file as described above with `fh = ...`

Comment: You created the path, but it doesn't mean that there is something at the end of the path...

Comment: This looks like Simulator. So log the full path and try it out in Terminal: `ls 'fullPath'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a simulator for this debugging process

### Verification

You should check if the file or `Resources` folder is actually being copied to the right location or not. If you have added the `Resources` folder, than check it with the below code

```
NSString *resourcesFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Resources" ofType:nil];
NSString *fullFilePath = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[demoToursPath,"filename.txt"]];

NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSLog(@"Filepath: %@", fullFilePath);
NSLog(@"File Exist: %@", [manager fileExistsAtPath:fullFilePath]);
```

Once you have confirmed this, you can update your code to match the location and path it needs to be in order to access the file.

### Additional Debug

You can also just print the `Document Directory` for the application and open a finder window and navigate there to see if the `Resources` folder is added at the right place (if it was added)

```
NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]

NSLog(@"Document Directory: %@", documentDir);
```

*If you update the question with more info, I would be able to help you better*